# mount ftp host in linux file system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, mount, nautilus

I tried curlftpfs and can copy files etc., but opening media files in totem or vlc fails with read errors. Any suggestions?

I'd try to use gvfs-mount instead, but don't know how to pass an option similar to custom_list="LIST" which tells curlftpfs to use LIST instead of LIST -a.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you _need_ the `-a` option? Gvfs should handle it itself.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because your bandwidth to the FTP you mounted is to slow.
I use SSHFS alot and even that with machines on the same local network has problems

Comment: it's the ftp server of my local router, should be fast enough